# NSPredicate object model array filter not working its crashing in Swift 4.0

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, filter, nspredicate

1. I'm working in swift 4.0, i have model object in MutableArray,
               NSPredicate not working.

   ```
                //Here is code
               //Model class:
               class Modelclass: NSObject
               {
                   var firstName:String!
                   var lastName:String!
               }

               // Viewcontroller doing predicate:
               let ary = NSMutableArray()

               let userModel          = Modelclass()
               userModel.firstName    = "Arrya"
               userModel.lastName     = "stark"
               ary.add(userModel)

               let commitPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "firstName == %@", "Arrya")
               let resultAry       = ary.filtered(using: commitPredicate)
               print(resultAry)
   ```

Comment: use `[Modelclass]` instead of `NSMutableArray`, swifty way

Comment: Also change 'let' to 'var' like this
I have Changed your code into this and working fine
var ary : [Modelclass] = []
ary.append(userModel)
let resultAry = ary.filter{ $0.firstName == "Arrya" }

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem,
 Solution 1:

```
    //I just added below code in model class

    extension Modelclass {
        @objc override func value(forKey key: String) -> Any? {
            switch key {
            case "firstName":
                return firstName
            case "lastName":
                return lastName
            default:
                return nil
            }
        } 
   }
```

Solution 2:

Add @objc before variable:

```
        class Modelclass: NSObject
        {
            @objc var firstName:String!
            @objc var lastName:String!

        }
```

Comment: Adding `@objc` before `var firstName:String!` (=> `@objc var firstName:String!` should do it too, avoiding you do override yourself `value(forKey:)`.

Answer (score 1):

1. `var` is introduced for Mutable Content/Variables
2. In swift you can use `filter` alternative to `NSPredicate`

Try Like this:

```
            //Model class:
            class Modelclass
            {
                var firstName: String
                var lastName: String

                init(firstName: String, lastName: String) {
                    self.firstName = firstName
                    self.lastName = lastName
                }
            }

            // Viewcontroller doing predicate:
            var ary:[Modelclass] = []

            let userModel = Modelclass(firstName: "Arrya", lastName: "stark")
            ary.append(userModel)

            let resultAry = ary.filter{ $0.firstName == "Arrya" }
            print(resultAry)
```

Comment: Ya good, is this possible to filter BEGINSWITH search like NSPredicate(format: "(firstName BEGINSWITH[cd] %@)","Ar") ?

Comment: $0.firstName.hasPrefix("Ar")